# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, discord.js javascrpt

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

im currently making a discord bot that logs previous messages then sends them as they are deleted/edited and i finished off all my code but now my terminal is all filled with errors saying

```
    at Function.normalizeField (C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:425:23)       
    at C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:445:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:444:8)       
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:259:42)        
    at MessageEmbed.addField (C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:250:17)
    at module.exports (C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\Events\messageUpdate.js:8:2)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\index.js:26:38)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_UPDATE] (C:\NewCrackHeadsBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_UPDATE.js:14:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8396) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

this error floods my terminal and im not sure how to fix it

this is the code where i believe the error is from but im a beginner so im not sure if any other code is needed i can show

```js
bot.on('messageUpdate', async(oldMessage,newMessage) => {

    require('./Events/messageUpdate')(oldMessage,newMessage)

})
bot.on('messageDelete', async(message) =>{

    require('./Events/messageDelete')(message)

})
```

this is the code i have in my messageDelete file

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
module.exports=async(message)=>{
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`New message deleted!`)
    .setDescription(`**The user ${message.author} has deleted a message in <#${message.channel.id}>**`)
    .addField(`content`,message.content,true)
    .setColor(`RED`)
    let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch=>ch.name==="bot-log")
    if(!channel)return;
    channel.send(embed)



}
```

this is the code i have in my message update file

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require(`discord.js`)
module.exports=async(oldMessage,newMessage)=>{

let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`New message edited`)
.setColor(`GREEN`)
.setDescription(`**The user ${oldMessage.author} has edited a message in <#${oldMessage.channel.id}>**`)
.addField(`Old Content`,oldMessage.content,true)
.addField(`New Content`,newMessage.content,true)
let channel = oldMessage.guild.channels.cache.find(ch=>ch.name==="bot-log")
if(!channel)return;
channel.send(embed)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure but I think you need await since you have async.

Are there errors in the other parts of your code too? If so, you might want to put it on the question too. (Sorry, I can't comment yet)

Comment: usually we use `await` with `async` but await is not essentially needed